# Загрузка гиф файлов с анимацией и без

Tags: gif, php

Ребят, не могу загрузить гиф файл с анимацией и без неё на сервер.

Вот код:

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="64000">
  Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file">
   <input type="submit" value="Send File">
   </form>

     <?php
     $valid_types   =  array("gif","jpg", "png", "jpeg");

  if (isset($_FILES["userfile"])) {

       if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
       $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
       $ext = substr($_FILES['userfile']['name'],1 + strrpos($_FILES['userfile']['name'],     "."));

    if (!in_array($ext, $valid_types)) {
        echo 'Unsupported type';
    } else {
           $size = GetImageSize($filename);
                 if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
                echo "загружено";
            } else {
                echo 'не загружено';
            }
}
     } }
  ?>
```

Comment: Может, ошибки какие выдает? Но осмелюсь предположить, что расширение gd2 не подключено.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Загружал картинки не из дериктории. Мой косяк.